# Get all files open for writing with pid, recursively

Tags: process, lsof

Given a pid, I can get all the files open for writing something like:

```
lsof -p 28827 | awk '$4 ~ "[wW]"{print $(NF-1), $NF}'
```

One of those ends up being a pipe:

```
28827 232611 pipe
```

I want to look-up all the files open by that pipe. If I just do:

```
lsof | grep 232611
```

That gives me a bunch of processes, one of which is a `tee`:

```
COMMAND     PID   TID    USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
<app>     28827       <me>       1w     FIFO                0,8       0t0  232611 pipe
<app>     28827 28836 <me>       1w     FIFO                0,8       0t0  232611 pipe
<app>     28827 28901 <me>       1w     FIFO                0,8       0t0  232611 pipe
....
tee       28828       <me>       0r     FIFO                0,8       0t0  232611 pipe
```

How can I programmatically find the `PID` for the `tee` (or generally, any process open with `r` access)? I can't simply check `$4 ~ "r"` since for most of the rows, `$4` isn't even the `FD` column.

Comment: What OS are you using? Is this Linux or another *nix?

Comment: Linux, RHEL 7.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be enough to just grep for digits followed by one or more `r`s:

```
lsof | grep -P '\b\d+r+\b'
```

Or, if you don't have GNU grep:

```
lsof | grep -E '\b[0-9]+r+\b'
```

The `\b`s mark word boundaries and ensure that only entire fields are matched. Alternatively, if your grep supports it, you can use the `-w` flag:

```
lsof | grep -wE '[0-9]+r+'
```

So, using that, you can get the relevant PIDs with

```
lsof | grep -wE '[0-9]+r+' a | awk '{print $2}'
```

---

@derobert pointed out in the comments below that, had I taken the time to actually read through the 2562 lines of `man lsof`, I would have found that it offers an `-F` option that lets you choose the fields printed. To get the file's access type, use `a`:

```
lsof -p 28827 -F a
```

Comment: Might also want to look at "OUTPUT FOR OTHER PROGRAMS" in the lsof manpage.

Comment: @derobert Can you elaborate? I've read that section and I cannot come up with a sequence of arguments that does the right thing for me.

Comment: @derobert I admit that the `lsof` manpage is one of the scariest documents I've ever tried to read. Right up there with _Ulysses_ and `man rsync`. I did find something that's probably relevant with your hint though, thanks.

Comment: @terdon `lsof -p 28827 -F a` just gives me a bunch of `a`s, `au`s, `aw`s, and `ar`s.

Comment: @Barry yeah, it prints everything on its own line, very annoying. You'll have the first line with `pNNN`, that's the PID. The rest will be `a[rwu]` and are the access types. You switch to the next entry when you have another line starting with `p`.

Comment: @terdon I'm accepting this since the first part with the `grep` did help me solve the problem - but I still have no idea how the `-F` helps me.